# how to campare two tables data in one database

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I have two table in my database one table1 contains all the sms record the user send or receive and table2 contains the list of official numbers .Now i want to compare these two tables data table1 phoneNumbers field and table2 official phone number field  if the numbers did not match i want to display it in red color otherwise it appears in the normal theme .so when the user is watching the table1 data phone number field in red color indicates that the number is not official my problem is when i compare these two records my table1 data rows repeated the number of time the total rows in table2 i don't want that I just want that table1 fetch all its record and red font color of phone number field indicates the reader that its not an official number here is my code

message.jsp

```
 try{
        String emi=request.getParameter("emi");
        imei=emi;
        String month=request.getParameter("month");
        String day=request.getParameter("dt");
        String year=request.getParameter("year");
        String month1=request.getParameter("month1");
        String day1=request.getParameter("dt1");
        String year1=request.getParameter("year1");
        String date =month+" "+day+" "+year;
        String date1=month1+" "+day1+" "+year1;
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(date1);

       Connection con = history.show.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from sms where  s_imei='"+emi+"' and  sms_date between '"+date+"' and '"+date1+"'");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next())
                   {
                        PreparedStatement  ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select * from ofcNumbers");
        ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
              while(rs1.next())
              {
             String num1=rs1.getString("phone_number");    





    %>

    <tr >
     <td >   
      <%
               if(num1.toString().trim().contains(rs.getString("sms_phoneNumber").toString().trim()))
                  {

         %>

     <%= rs.getString("sms_phoneNumber")+"sa"%>

         <%
                  break;}
               else{
                   %>
                  <font color="ff0000"><%= rs.getString("sms_phoneNumber")%></font>
              <% 
               }%>

     <td>    
     <%= rs.getString("sms_personName")%>
     <td>
      <%= rs.getString("sms_type")%>
      <td>
      <%= rs.getString("sms_date")%>
      <td>
      <%= rs.getString("sms_Time")%>
      <td>
      <%= rs.getString("s_logType")%>


    </tr>

     <tr class="alt" >
         <td class="alt" colspan="6" ><%= rs.getString("sms_body")%>

    <% }//end of for loop
       }  //end of while

       }
       //end of try
     catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sms s
LEFT OUTER JOIN ofcNumbers n on n.phone_number = s.phone_number
```

This would list all your SMS table data.
But with NULL values for "ofcNumbers" table ID column (hope you have ID column here) for which there aren't any records in ofcNumbers table matching the phone_numbers in SMS table.

Then you can do a check in your jsp, something like

```
if(rs.getValue("ofcNumbers_id") == NULL){
      <font color="ff0000"><%= rs.getString("sms_phoneNumber")%></font>
}
....
```